# How can I get the terminal in full resolution when running Ubuntu CLI in VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, terminal

I've installed Ubuntu (latest version) with CLI only, inside VirtualBox running in Windows 7 x64. Switching to fullscreen (`CTRL + F` in my setup) works, but of course the terminal windows has a low resolution (it's just a box inside a black background).

I think that guest additions are missing. How to enjoy the full 1080p terminal in Windows?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. If you want to change your resolution in full screen you will need to install guest additions. To install guest additions launch the VM, then from the devices menu, select install guest additions.

Comment: The problem is without X window additions won't install.

Answer (score 0):

I found this set of instructions worked for me:

[Installing guest additions in debian](http://virtualboxes.org/doc/installing-guest-additions-on-debian/)

Can't guarantee it will work in Ubuntu but I see no reason it wouldn't. Once the guest additions are installed ok you should be able to Ctrl F and view full screen. If this does not work you could install SSH and use that full screen to access the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup VirtualBox guest additions as you would normally do in a desktop version.
Obviously the diffence is, after you tell VirtualBox to mount the "VirtualBox Guest Additions disk" you'll have to enter the directory manually.

In your terminal navigate to the disk directory( usually in /media) and run the guest additions script:

`cd /media/"VirtualBoxGuestAddition"`

where name between "" is the name of the virtual disk and do

`sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

Follow the instructions and reboot.

You should have guest additions installed after that so you would be able to run the virtual system into fullscreen.